# How to change / switch mapsets in GRASS using cmd

Tags: grass-gis

I am using GRASS 7.0.4 I have created a new mapset to the LOCATION using cmd in it. But unable to switch back to old mapset. can anyone guide me??

Answer (score 2):

From grass terminal,

```
g.mapset mapset=MAPSETNAME location=LOCATIONNAME dbase=PATH\TO\YOUR\GRASSDB\DIR
```

You can change mapset in other directory.